# 403 ACCESS TOKEN SCOPE INSUFFICIENT using Campaign Manager 360 API and Postman

Tags: google-cloud-platform, postman

I am trying to access Campaign Manager 360 API campaign data using Postman GET method URL:
[https://dfareporting.googleapis.com/dfareporting/v4/userprofiles/{ProfileID}/campaigns](https://dfareporting.googleapis.com/dfareporting/v4/userprofiles/%7BProfileID%7D/campaigns).
This call out will give me a list of campaigns under this profileID.
I have the Bearer Token as well as clientID, client Secret etc stored inside Postman.

I am using the following 3 scopes - for Campaign Manager 360 -  inside Postman.
I don't know why I am getting this error because I have not accidentally added any ".readonly" permissions at the end of a scope path. I know that there have been issues from other getting this 403 error that have that appended at the end of a scope but not mine.
Thanks :

> 1. https://www.googleapis.com/auth/dfareporting
> 2. https://www.googleapis.com/auth/ddmconversions
> 3. https://www.googleapis.com/auth/dfatrafficking

When I send the request  I get the following:
[image]